MFC Problem with method that returns a pointer to other DLL module's class
I have an MFC app which is a semestral final project at the university. The project's solution includes two DLL modules: Except1 (handling errors and displaying messages), MyData (managing application data) and ProjectMFC that compiles to .exe file (the proper application project).
The project's dependencies look like below:
Except1
|
|-->MyData
|     |
|     v
|-->ProjectMFC

According to the project guidelines in MyData and ProjectMFC files I have to create a declaration of pointer to Except1 module's class in order to use methods from this module.
CExcept1App* pExcept;
In ProjectMFC it works.
But in MyData I get a linker error
Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol GetExceptPtr referenced in function "public: __cdecl MY_DATA::MY_DATA(int)" (??0MY_DATA@@QEAA@H@Z)        
although I've added additional dependencies in MyData project's properties.
MyData.h:
// MyData.h : main header file for the MyData DLL
//

#pragma once

#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
    #error "include 'pch.h' before including this file for PCH"
#endif

#include "resource.h"       // main symbols
#include "Except1.h"

#ifdef MY_DATA_EXPORTS
#define MYDATA_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDATA_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif // MY_DATA_EXPORTS

// CMyDataApp
// See MyData.cpp for the implementation of this class
//

//template <class T, class Key>
//T* find(const T* p_begin, const T* p_end, const Key& k)
//{
//  if (p_begin >= p_end)
//      return NULL;
//
//  T* p_tmp = const_cast<T*>(p_begin);
//  for (; p_tmp != p_end; p_tmp++)
//  {
//      if (*p_tmp == key)
//          return p_tmp;
//  }
//  return NULL;
//}

class CMyDataApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    CMyDataApp();

// Overrides
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

class CExcept1App;

class MYDATA_API MY_POINT
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    char* name = NULL;
    COLORREF color;

    MY_POINT() : x(0), y(0), name(NULL), color(RGB(0, 0, 0)){}
    MY_POINT(double xx, double yy, COLORREF c_color, const char* nname);
    MY_POINT(const MY_POINT& ob);
    ~MY_POINT() 
    { 
        if (name) 
            delete[] name;
        name = NULL;
    }

    MY_POINT& operator=(const MY_POINT& ob);
    void set(double xx, double yy, COLORREF c_color, const char* nname);
    MY_POINT get() { return *this; }

};

class MYDATA_API MY_DATA : public MY_POINT
{
protected:
    MY_POINT* pTab;
    int capacity;
    int last;
public:
    CExcept1App* pExcept;
    MY_DATA(int no_it);
    MY_DATA(const MY_DATA& ob);
    ~MY_DATA() { Free(); }
    int size() { return last; }
    void Free() { if (pTab) delete[] pTab; pTab = NULL; }
    void Init(int no_it);
    void Push(const MY_POINT& tmp);
    int Size() { return last; }
    void clear() { last = 0; }

    MY_POINT& operator [] (const int i) {
        return pTab[i];
    }
    void GetMaxMinCoords(double& max_x, double& min_x, double& max_y, double& min_y);


private:
    MY_POINT* allocTab(MY_POINT* pTab, int n);
};


MyData.cpp:
// MyData.cpp : Defines the initialization routines for the DLL.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "MyData.h"

#include <iostream>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

// CMyDataApp

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDataApp, CWinApp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CMyDataApp construction

CMyDataApp::CMyDataApp()
{
    // TODO: add construction code here,
    // Place all significant initialization in InitInstance
}


// The one and only CMyDataApp object

CMyDataApp theApp;

// CMyDataApp initialization

BOOL CMyDataApp::InitInstance()
{
    CWinApp::InitInstance();

    return TRUE;
}

MY_POINT::MY_POINT(double xx, double yy, COLORREF c_color, const char* nname = nullptr) : x(xx), y(yy), color(c_color)
{
    try
    {
        if (name)
        {
            name = new char[strlen(nname) + 1];
            strcpy_s(name, strlen(nname) + 1, nname);
        }
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc)
    {
        //pExcept->PutMessage(1001);
        name = NULL;
    }
}

MY_POINT::MY_POINT(const MY_POINT& ob)
{
    x = ob.x;
    y = ob.y;
    color = ob.color;

    try
    {
        if (ob.name)
        {
            name = new char[strlen(ob.name) + 1];
            strcpy_s(name, strlen(ob.name) + 1, ob.name);
        }
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc)
    {
        //pExcept->PutMessage(1001);
        name = NULL;
    }
}

MY_POINT& MY_POINT::operator=(const MY_POINT& ob)
{
    if (this == &ob) return *this;

    delete[] name;
    name = NULL;

    x = ob.x;
    y = ob.y;
    color = ob.color;
    try
    {
        if (ob.name)
        {
            name = new char[strlen(ob.name) + 1];
            strcpy_s(name, strlen(ob.name) + 1, ob.name);
        }
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc)
    {
        //pExcept->PutMessage(1001);
        name = NULL;
    }
    
    return *this;
}

void MY_POINT::set(double xx, double yy, COLORREF c_color, const char* nname)
{
    x = xx;
    y = yy;
    color = c_color;

    delete[] name;
    name = NULL;

    try
    {
        if (name)
        {
            name = new char[strlen(nname) + 1];
            strcpy_s(name, strlen(name) + 1, nname);
        }
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc)
    {
        //pExcept->PutMessage(1001);
        name = NULL;
    }
}

MY_DATA::MY_DATA(int no_it)
{
    pExcept = GetExceptPtr();
    pTab = NULL;
    Init(no_it);
}

MY_POINT* MY_DATA::allocTab(MY_POINT* pTab, int n)
{
    try
    {
        if (!pTab)
        {
            pTab = new MY_POINT[n];
            capacity = n;
        }
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc aa)
    {
        //pExcept->PutMessage(1001);
    }
    return pTab;
}
//it's the part of code using pExcept pointer

Except1.h:
// Except1.h : main header file for the Except1 DLL
//

#pragma once

#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
    #error "include 'pch.h' before including this file for PCH"
#endif

#include "resource.h"       // main symbols

#ifdef EXCEPT1_EXPORT
#define EXCEPT1_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXCEPT1_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// CExcept1App
// See Except1.cpp for the implementation of this class
//

#define APP_START_MESSAGE WM_USER+100

enum ITS_APP_MESSAGE
{
    WM_START = APP_START_MESSAGE,
    WM_DIS_MSG,
    WM_CLEAR_OUTPUT,
    WM_DIS_TOTALMES
};

class MY_DATA;

class EXCEPT1_API CExcept1App : public CWinApp
{
public:
    CWnd* ptrWnd;
    MY_DATA* ptrDat;

public:
    CExcept1App();
    void SetWnd(CWnd* ptrwnd, MY_DATA* pdat) { ptrWnd = ptrwnd; ptrDat = pdat; }
    void ResetDat(MY_DATA* pdat) { ptrDat = pdat; }
    void PutMessage(UINT ID_MESSAGE);
    void ClearOutWnd();

// Overrides
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

extern "C" CExcept1App * PASCAL EXPORT GetExceptPtr();```




GetExceptPtr() is also in Except1.def file:
Except1.def : Declares the module parameters for the DLL.

LIBRARY

EXPORTS
    ; Explicit exports can go here
    GetExceptPtr

Except1.cpp:
// Except1.cpp : Defines the initialization routines for the DLL.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "Except1.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

// CExcept1App

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CExcept1App, CWinApp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CExcept1App construction

CExcept1App::CExcept1App()
{
    // TODO: add construction code here,
    // Place all significant initialization in InitInstance
    ptrWnd = NULL;
    ptrDat = NULL;
}


// The one and only CExcept1App object

CExcept1App theApp;


// CExcept1App initialization

BOOL CExcept1App::InitInstance()
{
    CWinApp::InitInstance();

    return TRUE;
}


void CExcept1App::PutMessage(UINT ID_Message)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandleA(NULL);
    char str[1024];
    int ret = LoadStringA(hInstance, ID_Message, str, sizeof(str));
    if (ptrWnd)
        ptrWnd->SendMessage(WM_DIS_MSG, (WPARAM)str, (LPARAM)ptrDat);
    else if (!ptrWnd && str[0] == 'E')
    {
        CString sstr(str);
        AfxMessageBox(sstr);
        UINT uExitCode = 0;
        HANDLE hHandle = GetCurrentProcess();
        TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), uExitCode);
    }
}

void CExcept1App::ClearOutWnd()
{
    if (ptrWnd)
        ptrWnd->SendMessage(WM_CLEAR_OUTPUT, 0, 0);
}

extern "C" CExcept1App * PASCAL EXPORT GetExceptPtr()
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
    return &theApp;
}



I've tried to use forward declaration because both Except1 and MyData use their pointers but it didn't solve the problem.

EDIT:
MyData Properties:
C/C++ options
Linker options
Custom builds steps

just add EXCEPT1_API after extern "C" in GetExceptPtr declaration.

Why are you using PASCAL EXPORT instead of EXCEPT1_API on this function? And why have you not made it a member of the CExcept1App class?

@OldBoy The answer is simply. Except1 module is part of the code that was written by my professor (I only have to add messages content and use it in MyData 'catch' blocks). So rewrite this code never occurred to me.

@AhmedAEK I tried it but I've got the same error code with a minimal difference. There is __imp_GetExceptPtr instead of GetExceptPtr

As far as I can see, both Mydata and Except1 are main programs, and each one makes cross references to the other. You should make one of them a pure stand-alone library (aka dll) and the other the main program.

@OldBoy Do you know how to make in this case a pure stand-alone library? Is it all about not including additional dependencies to this dll?

Your question says "The project's solution includes two DLL modules: Except1 (handling errors and displaying messages), MyData (managing application data) ". But as far as I can see they are both main applications not dll libraries. So it is rather confusing what you are supposed to be doing.

@OldBoy Maybe I didn't explain it clearly. These two modules compile to dll libraries, so as you fairly noticed, they are actually main applications.

Sorry, that does not make sense. Either they are dll libraries, or they are main applications. The more I look at the code you have posted the more I find it confusing.

A reason why you get the unresolved external may be that you didn't include the import library for Except1.dll (ie Except1.lib) in the MyData project; including the header file only is not enough. Another reason could be bad function signature. Apart from these your setup has more issues: You don't need an application class for just throwing an exception. Also beware of possible heap corruption: traditionally, memory allocated in a module may be referenced by another module, but it has to be deallocated by the same module that allocated it. MSCV/MFC uses a common memory allocator.

@ConstantineGeorgiou I have Except1.lib in custom build step. You can see in my edited post. Maybe you're right when it comes to using CExcept1App only to throwing exceptions, however this class also shows normal messages, e.g. write/save file and thanks to a pointer to MY_DATA class, can deallocate memory in case of fatal error. In addition, as I said in one of my previous comment, the Except1 was written by my professor so I can't even change it too much.

Importing and Exporting. Read this, all of it, thoroughly.

Sorry, but what I see in the pics isn't including Except1.lib in the MyData project, instead it's _copying MyData.lib to another folder ($(TargetName).lib, but for the MyData project, so it's MyData.lib). And the Custom Build Step is executed AFTER the compile/link ones. Except1.lib must be included in your project (MyData) either from Project Options->Linker->Additional Dependencies (I don't see anything there), or from Solution Explorer->Add->Existing Item. Also, the GetExceptPtr() declaration in Except1.h is wrong when included in MyData (it should be _declspec(dllimport)).

@ConstantineGeorgiou Yes, the problem was because I didn't include Except1.lib in Linker options. I was dead sure that Additional Dependencies in Custom Build Paths provides this file. Thank you and other guys for help.
